# Fetching XML within Android program

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am currently developing an android program. After some searching i can't seem to find out a solution to fetch or request using XML within my android program.

I'm still at the early stages of the program. I can show the xml code i will be using. It's basically requesting data using a username and password. I want to use this data so that the user can for example in a text/input box use the MonitoringRef identifier and receive the data through the XML request and have it presented within the app.

A request would consist of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Siri version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/">
<ServiceRequest>
<RequestTimestamp>2007-01-11T10:38:12Z</RequestTimestamp>
<RequestorRef>CLIENT_APP_ID</RequestorRef>
<StopMonitoringRequest version="1.0">
<RequestTimestamp>2007-01-11T10:38:12Z</RequestTimestamp>
<MessageIdentifier>67890</MessageIdentifier>
<MonitoringRef>260057046</MonitoringRef>
</StopMonitoringRequest>
</ServiceRequest>
</Siri>
```

A response would consist of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
10 - 11
Kizoom Traveline API at 03/09/2010
<Siri version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.siri.org.uk/">
<ServiceDelivery>
<ResponseTimestamp>2007-05-22T14:39:04+01:00</ResponseTimestamp>
<StopMonitoringDelivery version="1.0">
<ResponseTimestamp>2007-05-
22T14:39:04+01:00</ResponseTimestamp>
<RequestMessageRef>12345</RequestMessageRef>
<MonitoredStopVisit>
<RecordedAtTime>2007-05-22T14:39:03+01:00</RecordedAtTime>
<MonitoringRef>leiadadg</MonitoringRef>
<MonitoredVehicleJourney>
<FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
<DataFrameRef>-</DataFrameRef>
<DatedVehicleJourneyRef>-</DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
</FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
<VehicleMode>bus</VehicleMode>
<PublishedLineName>22</PublishedLineName>
<DirectionName>Norwich: Rail Station
Forecourt</DirectionName>
<MonitoredCall>
<AimedDepartureTime>2007-05-
22T14:53:00+01:00</AimedDepartureTime>
<ExpectedDepartureTime>2007-05-
22T14:55:00+01:00</ExpectedDepartureTime>
</MonitoredCall>
</MonitoredVehicleJourney>
</MonitoredStopVisit>
</StopMonitoringDelivery>
<StopMonitoringDelivery version="1.0">
<ResponseTimestamp>2007-05-
22T14:39:04+01:00</ResponseTimestamp>
<RequestMessageRef>67890</RequestMessageRef>
<MonitoredStopVisit>
<RecordedAtTime>2007-05-22T14:39:03+01:00</RecordedAtTime>
<MonitoringRef>260057046</MonitoringRef>
<MonitoredVehicleJourney>
<FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
<DataFrameRef>-</DataFrameRef>
<DatedVehicleJourneyRef>-</DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
</FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
<VehicleMode>bus</VehicleMode>
<PublishedLineName>3</PublishedLineName>
<DirectionName>Norwich: Ber Street John
Lewis</DirectionName>
<MonitoredCall>
<AimedDepartureTime>2007-05-
22T14:53:00+01:00</AimedDepartureTime>
<ExpectedDepartureTime>2007-05-
22T14:57:00+01:00</ExpectedDepartureTime>
</MonitoredCall>
</MonitoredVehicleJourney>
</MonitoredStopVisit>
<MonitoredStopVisit>
<RecordedAtTime>2007-05-22T14:39:03+01:00</RecordedAtTime>
<MonitoringRef>260057046</MonitoringRef>
<MonitoredVehicleJourney>
<FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
<DataFrameRef>-</DataFrameRef>
<DatedVehicleJourneyRef>-</DatedVehicleJourneyRef>
</FramedVehicleJourneyRef>
<VehicleMode>bus</VehicleMode>
<PublishedLineName>18</PublishedLineName>
<DirectionName>Old Catton: White Woman Lane/Proctor
Rd</DirectionName>
<MonitoredCall>
<AimedDepartureTime>2007-05-
22T14:57:00+01:00</AimedDepartureTime>
</MonitoredCall>
</MonitoredVehicleJourney>
</MonitoredStopVisit>
</StopMonitoringDelivery>
</ServiceDelivery>
</Siri>
```

Element in XML:

- StopMonitoringDelivery –present for
  each StopMonitoringRequest in the
  request
- RequestMessageRef – corresponds to
  MessageIdentifier in the request
- MonitoringRef – indicates which bus
  stop this StopMonitoringDelivery
  relates to
- MonitoredStopVisit – represents a
  single bus departure
- PublishedLineName –service name
- DirectionName – destination
- AimedDepartureTime –scheduled
  departure time
- ExpectedDepartureTime –estimated
  departure time

I'm just wondering if anyone can provide me to resources or a solution to provide this within the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interact with remote service via HTTP protocol using [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)  and [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) / [HttpGet](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) classes.

To parse an XML document from string response you can use [DocumentBuilder.parse method](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream%29)
It will provide to you an implementation of [W3C Document Object Model](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) to work with.

Also, you'll need to use some serialization facility to prepare a string representation of you XML document (to send as a response or else). The solution is depends on minimal SDK version of your application. With API level 8 you can use [LSSerializer](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html) to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much for that! I'll research more into those areas you mentioned.